# Why Can't I add this repository?

Tags: server, apt, package-management, repository, owncloud-server

I am trying to install Owncloud on my Ubuntu server 15.04 system.

I used the following code to add the repository to install Owncloud:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/xUbuntu_15.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list"
```

However, when I run this code, I get this error:

```
Cannot create /etc/apt/ssources.list.d/owncloud.list: Directory nonexistent
```

How can I fix this issue, and get Owncloud installed?

Comment: The error and your command do not match. The command is correct. But I assume, that you used the comand `sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/xUbuntu_15.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/ssources.list.d/owncloud.list"` and not `sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/xUbuntu_15.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list"`

Answer (score 4):

The error is self explanatory.  Basically, what your command that you say you're running, and the actual command you *are* running are different, and you need to double check the exact command you're running.

In the command you *are* running, you've got **`/etc/apt/ssources.list.d/`**, which doesn't exist anywhere and shouldn't, so the command errors out.

What you *need* to be running is exactly what you pasted and said was the code you were using, which uses **`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`** which is the correct directory to use for the `owncloud.list` file.

Comment: @Tanner If this helps you, please hit the check mark button to mark this as the accepted answer.